# Rails 3 complex form with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have single form where i have vehicle details, complaint details and user details .Where vehicle has_many complaints and user has_many complaints .Its a nested_attribute form but for some reason i feel the association is wrong and im little confused how the form should be Or It should be complaint has_one vehicle and complaint has_one user?? 
And im creating new user and new vehicle when im creating a complaint.This form doesn't have any authentication ..

Vehicle.rb

```
 class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :number, :vehicle_types , :complaints_attributes
   has_many :complaints
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :complaints
 end
```

User.rb

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address, :email_id, :mobile , :complaints_attributes
  has_many :complaints
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :complaints
 end
```

Complaint.rb

```
class Complaint < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :indecent_behaviour, :occurence_date_time, :other_complaints,      :place_occurence
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :vehicle 
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't make sense to me why users and vehicles would have nested complaints. You probably aren't creating complaints at the same time that you're creating new users and new vehicles. Are you?

Presumably a user is made, a vehicle is made, and then a user complains about a vehicle, at which point a complaint is made. Chronologically later than when the user or vehicle is created.

So, maybe take out the nested attributes. Instead, you could use a hidden field and pass the vehicle id as a parameter, or you could use a nested resource route to get the vehicle_id. Create the complaint through the has_many association of the current_user who is complaining:

```
new_complaint_path( vehicle_id: @vehicle.id )
```

in the complaint controller

```
def new
  @complaint = current_user.complaints.build
  @complaint[:vehicle_id] = params[:vehicle_id]
end
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..Yes im creating new user and new vehicle when im creating a complaint.. this form doesn't have any authentication ..